# CakePHP Having a variable in every file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I would like to have a variable `$bURL` available on every view/controller/element/layout of my CakePHP installation.

What is the best location to set such a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bootstrap.php](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp)

> This file is ideal for a number of common bootstrapping tasks:
>
> - Defining convenience functions.
> - **Registering global constants.**
> - ...